# Puppet module resource attributes

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

Is there a way to print the value of an attribute in a puppet module?  For example, if you have a file resource:

```
file {'myfile':
      path => '/this/is/my/path',
      ensure => present,
      owner => 'someuser',
      group => 'somegroup'
}
```

can you print the value of the 'path' attribute?  Perhaps using a notify?

```
notify {"the value of path is: " __________}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if you pass your attributes as literal strings.

However, you can re-use the attribute if you assign it to a variable. Example:

```
$file_path = '/this/is/my/path'

file { 'myfile':
  path   => $file_path,
  ensure => present,
  owner  => 'someuser',
  group  => 'somegroup'
}

notify { "the value of path is: ${file_path}": }
```

Note the final colon that separates the resource name and the parameters (in this case there are none, so the resource is just terminated). The `notify` above could also be written as this ([reference](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#notify)):

```
notify { 'my_notify':
  message =>  "the value of path is: ${file_path}",
}
```

Also, note the correct use of single and double quotes. According to Puppet Lint, [double quotes should only be used when the string contains an interpolated variable](http://puppet-lint.com/checks/double_quoted_strings/), and [such variables should be enclosed within curly braces](http://puppet-lint.com/checks/variables_not_enclosed/).

Comment: This is what I thought.  I was hoping someone had some sort of 'magic' to be able to get it another way.  Thanks!